# BeautifulSoup - How do I find values from a table with no id?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape values from the 'retained profit' row under the 'British Land Fundamentals' heading at https://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=financials&symbol=L%5EBLND

Not sure how to go about this as I can't see a specific ID or class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a working solution by finding the specific row name in the HTML source code and iterating through the table values in said row:

```
def foo(ticker):
    response = requests.get('https://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=financials&symbol=L%5E{}'.format(ticker))
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
# find all 'a' tags
    for a in soup.find_all("a"):
    # find the specific row we want, there is only one instance of the a tag with the text 'retained profit' so this works
        if a.text == "retained profit":
        # iterate through each value in the row
            for val in a.parent.find_next_siblings():
            # return only the values in bold (i.e. those tags with the class='sb' in this case)
                for class_ in val.attrs['class']:
                    if class_ == 'sb':
                        print(val.text)
```

Outputs the desired values from the table :D

Answer (score 0):

this return all tables with width 100%

u can try:

tables = soup.find_all('table',width="100%")

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
  for key,value in enumerate(tr.find_all("td")):
    anchor = value.find_all("a",class="Lcc")
      if "Retained Profit PS" in anchor.text:
        return  tr.find_all("td")[key+1]
```